# Selector placehoder for a single charcter

Tags: jquery, html, css, regex, jquery-selectors

I'm using a jQuery selector and I need to choose some elements based on the position of the characters. For example, I need to select those items that have the 3rd character as 'h' and 4th character as 'r'. From the below list, the selector should select the first two elements but not the third.

> abhres
>
> cdhrex
>
> efdghr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to write a custom selector http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/jquery-custom-selectors-with-parameters.html Bellow is an example of one that I think accomplishes what you are looking for. If not it shouldn't be hard to modify it to get what your looking for

```
$.expr[':']['nth-letter-eq'] = function (obj, index, meta, stack) {{
   var args = meta[3].split(",");
   var includeThisElement = false;
   if ($(obj).text().charAt(parseInt(args[0])) == args[1]) {
       includeThisElement = true;
   }
   return includeThisElement;
}
```

usage

```
$("p:nth-letter-eq(3,a)")
```

Answer (score 0):

See it here for the 3rd char as h

> http://regexr.com?37k0n

You can change this accordingly for the 4th char as r